# Redirecting to routes programatically using route names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following routes:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, {history: ReactRouter.hashHistory},
            React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {path: '/', component: AppController}),
            React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {component: LayoutController},
                React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardController}),
                React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {path: '/signout', component: UserSignoutController})
            )
        )
    , document.getElementById('content'));
```

This is how I redirect the application flow:

```
ReactRouter.browserHistory.push('/dashboard');
```

It works, but if I open my application on another machine with a different url structure, and I have to change url paths, I also have to change every `push` argument.

Is there a way to redirect using route names instead of paths?

Comment: I don't understand how a path like that would be different on another machine. Wouldn't you also have to configure a different path in the route if that's the case? BTW, that's probably not the ideal way to configure the routes. If you don't want to do it with JSX I'd suggest using [`PlainRoute`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/69b163255ca6fc363fe270911b1161378650cc1b/docs/API.md#plainroute) objects instead of writing out `React.createElement()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions it was possible to navigate by name, but AFAIK it is no longer working. In my opinion what you should do is to configure the basename of the history for your different servers, i.e. the prefix of the route. Take into account that the final part of the URL, the one that is configured by react-router is fixed.

In order to specify the basename, you should pass a custom history to the router.

`useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({ basename })`